# Dropbox API v2 get the original creator of a file

Tags: dropbox-api

Is there anyway to get the original creator of a file?

Using `/files/get_metadata` I can get some sharing info:

```
"sharing_info": {
    "read_only": true,
    "parent_shared_folder_id": "84528192421",
    "modified_by": "dbid:AAH4f99T0taONIb-OurWxbNQ6ywGRopQngc"
},
...
```

This tells me who was the last to modify the file but I am interested in who originally created the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the best you can do is to use [`/files/list_revisions`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_revisions) to walk back through the file's history. You can only go back as far as 100 revisions, though, so you won't be able to find the original creator of a file that's been modified more than 100 times.